# a href don't do anything in li menu slider (sliding block when li is hover)

Tags: jquery, menu, slider, href

I try using a slider menu from this site http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/category/client-side/jquery/#.

Everything is ok, but when I want put in a href some url if I click on this then do anything

Because why?

Thank for help!

Sorry for my language.

Regrets,
Kropamk

Comment: I don't see code for a slider on that page. However, it's most likely that there is a .preventDefault() on click of an <a> tag within the slider. Could you post your code sample?

Comment: Examples are at the bottom of the page. The finished plug (package) you can download from this site http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/36-eye-catching-jquery-navigation-menus/

Position 18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the return on the click event to **true**, on this method:

```
$(function() {
    $(".menu-lava").lavaLamp({
        fx: "backout",
        speed: 700,
        click: function(event, menuItem) {
            return false;  // <--- Here
        }
    });
});
```

It's on the HTML page. I hope this helps.